# Error when trying to call function on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am building a cross platform app using AngularJS, Monaca and Onsen UI.

I am trying to call a function in my controller from a ng-click() on my view. However, when I click the button that calls the function I get an error message saying: "*Uncaught ReferenceError: checkUserLoginDetails is not defined*"

My index.html looks as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <!-- Usual scripts goes here -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sharedProperties.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="login.html"></ons-navigator>
</body>
</html>
```

I cant see where I am going wrong here.

My 
This is my **login.html** where I call my function.

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
    <ons-page>
        <form class="login-form" style="text-align: center" name="myForm">
            <section style="padding: 8px">
                <input type="password" 
                    class="text-input--underbar" 
                    required 
                    minlength="3" 
                    maxlength="4" 
                    ng-model-options="{ debounce : 500 }"
                    placeholder="User ID" 
                    ng-model="userID" >
            </section>


            // Button not working here
            <section style="padding: 0 8px 8px">
                <ons-button var="saveBtn" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" modifier="large" ng-click="checkUserLoginDetails()">Log In</ons-button>
            </section>
        </form>
    </ons-page>
</div>
```

And this is my **loginController.js** code that handles the logic (logic omitted)

```
var login = angular.module("loginController", []);
login.controller("LoginController", function($scope, $http, SharedProperties)
{   
    // Watch for changes in the User ID text field
    $scope.$watch('userID', function(newVal, oldVal)
    {
       // Code omitted but WORKING
    });

    // Check user Logins
    $scope.checkUserLoginDetails = function()
    {
        console.log("Getting here..."); // Not getting here
    }
});
```

And in my main **app.js** I create the module that holds all the controllers - again this is working for all other views and controller (again omitted from the list as not needed) so I doubt the issue is here.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['onsen', 'sharedProperties', 'loginController']);
```

I have also tried *onclick* instead of *ng-click* but bot give the same error message.

Comment: Are you sure that your `section` is under the `loginController`?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I also have other functions on that controller to e.g. $watch() for changes in text fields and they are all working as expected. My view is setup as <div ng-controller="LoginController">
    <ons-page><section>...my section here</section></ons-page></div>

Comment: you need to see this https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/395.

Comment: we need more code to see what is wrong there because there is no reason for `ng-click` to not work and therefore I'd like to see the html section and app section. Please check if all things are initialized properly.

Comment: @Atula I also had a look at the link but the issue isn't that the button doesn't fire, the event on the button is triggered but it says the function is undefined?

Comment: can you try with normal button instead of ons-button. I just wanted to know.

Comment: @riteshmeher Yes I am still getting the same error if I use a normal button e.g. <section><button type="button" onclick="checkUserLoginDetails()">Click Me</button></section>

Comment: I think we need more code to see whats going on. whatever code you posted looks good to me. can you set up a plunk?

Comment: I think the login controller not under myApp module. The controller needs to be inside a module. I just added a module in the fiddle and it worked. Here is the fiddle link: https://fiddle.jshell.net/beroza/yhc9dm8w/

Comment: @riteshmeher I have added the last bit of code (index.html) but apart from that there isnt more to add that relates to this issue.

Comment: @Beroza Paul I have my controllers split into different files because the project has grown larger and having all my controllers in the 1 app.js files was getting hard to manage. My app.js creates the module that deals with the controllers - as per the code.

Answer (score 1):

If ons-page is a directive with transclution, then the function isn't available in the transclution body since directives with transclude create their own scopes.

Comment: Can you suggest a possible solution in this case please?

Comment: you can try to move the logic from the loginController into the ons-page directive